# Typescript: updating one class property automatically causes another to update

Tags: typescript

I have had a look for this and am having trouble finding anywhere that explains how to do this..

I have a class:

```
export class CalendarLayout {
   private displayedColumns: number;
   private displayedHours: number;
   private calendarStartDatePosition: moment.Moment;
   private dayDifference: number;


   constructor(
            displayedColumns: number,
            displayedHours: number,
            calendarStartDatePosition: moment.Moment,
            dayDifference: number
           ) {
    this.displayedColumns = displayedColumns;
    this.displayedHours = displayedHours;
    this.calendarStartDatePosition = calendarStartDatePosition;
    this.dayDifference = dayDifference;
}
```

}

I actually wanted dayDifference to be a calculated value based on calendarStartDatePosition.

```
dayDifference = this.calendarStartDatePosition.diff(moment(), 'days');
```

I have tried using getters and setters to no avail. Further, the compiler complained that it was not receiving a value for dayDifference..

How do you have a property of a class, in my case "dayDifference", that is by itself calculated from one of the other properties? Further, if I update the calendarStartDatePosition property the dayDifference propety automatically updates.

Comment: You're looking to define a getter, from the sounds of it.

Comment: Not sure how you do this properly

Comment: Something along the lines of `get dayDifference() { /* code that calculates value */ }` would suffice.

Comment: Take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. confused with the actual constructor on dayDifference... do you still declare it in the constructor as above or not..

Comment: If you're calculating it automatically, there's no need to explicitly set its value.

Comment: so leave it out of the constructor and set the property as public?

Comment: Just define a getter (as I linked to). That _is_ the property.

Comment: As a side note, given this isn't specific to TypeScript, the JavaScript tag could have sufficed here.

Comment: Does my answer help you?

Answer (score 1):

I've inlined comments in the code you've provided:

```js
export class CalendarLayout {
    private displayedColumns: number;
    private displayedHours: number;
    private calendarStartDatePosition: moment.Moment;
    // private dayDifference: number;

    // We can define a getter (private as before).
    // This will *automatically* calculate the relevant value
    // when asked (via `this.dayDifference`, no method call).
    private get dayDifference() {
        return this.calendarStartDatePosition.diff(moment(), 'days');
    }

    constructor(
        displayedColumns: number,
        displayedHours: number,
        calendarStartDatePosition: moment.Moment,
        // dayDifference: number // Calculated automatically
    ) {
        this.displayedColumns = displayedColumns;
        this.displayedHours = displayedHours;
        this.calendarStartDatePosition = calendarStartDatePosition;

        // We no longer need to set this, as we're calculating it as needed.
        // this.dayDifference = dayDifference;
    }
}
```

I'm not familiar with Moment.js, but you *might* want a global object that you can get the current time from; I believe the current code creates a new instance each call.